# Consequent overrides of core class

Tags: overrides, magento2.3.0

I have two modules:

1. Vendor_Module1
2. Vendor_Module2

In either module I'm going to extend `\Magento\Directory\Model\Currency` to override different methods

I noticed that only one module can override this class at the same time. The module that is placed lower in **config.php** will have precedence.

I guess something goes wrong. Till now I was absolutely sure that there is no any limitation on how many modules override any class. Who can tell me what I missed?

**(Each module overrides its own methods. Of course every time I clear cache, delete generated/code and so on)**

It's **Magento 2.3.0** if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

Plugin is best for this one. As it has a **sortOrder** for **prioritizing plugins**. check documentation

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html